# Print hash in view with new line for each key-value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Sometimes I choose to print out `params` or an object in a view, but when loaded with data it cannot be hard to visually scan.

Is their any "trick" to easily print a hash such that each key-value pair is printed on a new line?

In the console I use `y my_hash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No trick. There isn't any out-of-the-box way to do this. You'll have to format the hash.

An example:

```
puts( your_hash.map{ |k,v| "#{k} => #{v}" }.sort )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple alternative:

```
<% hash.each do |k,v| %>
  <%= k %>: <%= y %> <br />
<% end %>
```